# refine twilio token connection error

Tags: swift, twilio, twilio-api

At the moment, Users will get a "No internet connection" error, when the cloudfunctions API to get the Twilio token is offline or faulty. This should return a different error message. how do i refine the error message according to the kind of error encountered in swift?

```
class Token {
    let value: String
init (url: String = "userTokenURL") throws {
    guard let requestURL = URL(string: url) else {
        throw Token.Error.invalidURL
    }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: requestURL)
        guard let stringToken = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw Token.Error.couldNotConvertDataToString
        }
        value = stringToken
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print ("Error fetching token data, \(error)")
        throw Token.Error.noInternet
    }
}
}

extension Token {
enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case invalidURL
    case couldNotConvertDataToString
    case noInternet

    var description: String? {
        switch self {
        case .invalidURL:
            return NSLocalizedString("Token URL is invalid.", comment: "")
        case .couldNotConvertDataToString:
            return NSLocalizedString("Token Data could not be converted to String.", comment: "")
        case .noInternet:
            return NSLocalizedString("Internet connection failed.", comment: "")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here. What have you implemented? What is the code you are using to retrieve a token in your app?

Comment: @philnash updated with code. how do I capture more details about the exact failure reason of the api(look Into code)

Comment: Looks to me like you are already set up to send different error messages based on things going wrong. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: is there any way to get more details of the exact cause? "no internet" is too generic

Comment: I'm not too sure of the error that `Data(contentsOf)` throws, but if there's any more information about what caused the issue then it's likely to be in there.